# Validate user entered data by following requirements in PHP

Tags: php

How can one validate user entered data in these requirements:

1. in lower case letters,
2. no special characters, also no white space characters,
3. and also allow only one hyphen.

Comment: what is the code that you have tried ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A literal string in lower case letters with one hyphen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273384/a-literal-string-in-lower-case-letters-with-one-hyphen)  Don't re-post your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
if (!preg_match('/^(?=[a-z])(?=\-{1})$/', $string))
{
    //invalid
}
```